# Hibernate Mysql query exception for bitwise_or

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am getting SQL Grammar exception after using my biteise_or which I have registered in MySQL dialect. Not sure whats wrong?

```
String hql = "select address.exchange.id, bitwise_or(address.capabilities,address.capabilities) as tempValue from Address address"
            + " where address.type.id = 1 group by address.exchange.id ";
```

Answer (score 0):

HQL not supported bitwise after 'select' if you want to execute this query please go through criteria. but one thing is that we can we bitwise after 'Where clause ' in restriction like this 'where (r.Permissions & :param) > 0'
    best way use hibernate criteria